# How take attribut from response and write it to properties?

Tags: soapui, jsonpath

I have json-response in such form: "f42210c4-2c67-44b2-af6c-07021ed83743"
How can I take only guid (without quotes) and record it to properties for future use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Groovy (or Java) in SoapUI scripts, use

```
string = string.replace("\"", "");
```

to 'cut' the edges of your response.